# My RecyclerView activity displays blank activity

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i have developed an application which displays a list made using RecyclerView and card view by viewing tutorials(simplified coding).The cardview has two text views and one image view.I want to get the data from mysql databse and the image URL is loaded to image view using picasso. My application is running but not displaying anything and comes with error response.

My app gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.selvam.listapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'



    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My recycler_view xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.selvam.listapp.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My card_view xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="219dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.16">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="309dp"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

'My items to be listed' in a class

```
package com.example.selvam.listapp;

/**
 * Created by SELVAM on 11-09-2017.
 */

public class ListItems {
    private  String name;
    private  String price;
    private  String image;

    public ListItems(String name,String price,String image) {
        this.image=image;
        this.price=price;
        this.name=name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }


}
```

my Recycler Adapter is

```
package com.example.selvam.listapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by SELVAM on 11-09-2017.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItems> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<ListItems> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItems item=listItems.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        Picasso.with(context).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvPrice;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvPrice=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

My main activity with json parsing using volley is

```
package com.example.selvam.listapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_LIST="http://192.168.28.2/signup/activities/getDataToListview.php";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<ListItems> listitems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listitems=new ArrayList<>();
        loadRecyclerView();

    }
    public void loadRecyclerView(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading lists...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_LIST, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                   JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject js=array.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItems item=new ListItems(
                                js.getString("name"),js.getString("price"),js.getString("image")
                        );
                        listitems.add(item);
                    }
                    adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(listitems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lists cannot be displayed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
        );
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
           }
```

my json output from mysql database is

```
{"list":[{"name":"messi","price":"hundred","image":"http:\/\/192.168.28.2\/img\/messi.jpeg"},{"name":"goat","price":"twohundred","image":"http:\/\/192.168.28.2\/img\/goat.jpg"},{"name":"cristiano","price":"threehundred","image":"http:\/\/192.168.28.2\/img\/cr7.jpg"}]}
```

I searched and tried a lot. Please help me with my mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: you should notify adapter after changing data in it put this -->> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: tried it...but still no display@PratikTank

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

Step 1: Check **width** of recyclerView = **0dp**. try change = **"match_parent"**. If it not working, try Step2

Step 2: Try code below:

```
public void loadRecyclerView(){
final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("loading lists...");
progressDialog.show();
adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(listitems,getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                    // display response     
        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        try {
               JSONArray array=response.getJSONArray("list");

                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject js=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    ListItems item=new ListItems(
                            js.getString("name"),js.getString("price"),js.getString("image")
                    );
                    listitems.add(item);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
        Log.d("Error.Response", response);
   }
}
);

RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(getRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the list in the adapter.
Add this method to the adapter

```
public void setItems(List<ListItems> list) {
this.list = list;
}
```

and call it like this

```
adapter.setItems(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding data to your list.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment.I have added.but still no lists... Please try to verify again...@Elinor